# Route view don't load CSS Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The CSS don't load em some routes, example, a route with a var:

```
   //LINK
    Route::get('/link/{id}', 'PagesController@link');
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/style.css">,
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: use the asset helper. Or the Mix helper if you are using Laravel mix

Answer (score 1):

To generate URL's for assets like CSS/JS/images/etc., in Laravel, use the helper function `asset`, instead of specifying the relative URL:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
```

[See the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset)

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/css/style.css') }} ">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }} ">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute paths like this (starting from the end of 'public'):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">,
```

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is the following one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Don't forget to add the `/` before the `css/style.css` or it wont load.